# Boolean exercise

Tags: ruby, boolean-logic

I am working on the following exercise in a course and I cannot wrap my head around this. I am very new to learning Rails, so please be patient with me. Currently the exercise wants me to write a method named `tasty?`, which takes one argument:

```
def tasty?(ripe)  
end
```

`tasty?` should:

- return "Yes" if `ripe` is `true`
- return "Not Yet" if `ripe` is `false`

Specs are:

```
describe "tasty?" do  
  it "should return 'Yes' if ripe is true" do  
    expect( tasty?(true) ).to eq("Yes")  
  end  
  it "should return 'Not Yet' if ripe is false" do  
    expect( tasty?(false) ).to eq("Not Yet")  
  end  
end
```

I wrote this:

```
def tasty?(ripe)  
  if "ripe == 'yes'"  
    ( tasty?("true") ).==("yes")  
  end  
  if "ripe == 'not yet'"  
    ( tasty?("false") ).==("not yet")  
  end  
end
```

And receive this message when I run it:

```
exercise.rb:4: warning: string literal in condition  
exercise.rb:7: warning: string literal in condition
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @CarySwoveland these kind of comments are called answers ;-)

Comment: Readers: @Stefan was referring to a comment that I subsequently converted to an answer. I seem to have posted quite a few answers that began as what were to be brief comments.

Comment: Thank you both for making my code clearer! Guess I'd better go back through Stackoverflow's tutorial on how to do this! :)

Comment: Being a newbie here I can see why you wanted to thank each person who gave an answer individually, and since all were good answers, that's fine. In future, however, you may wish to restrain yourself. For one, thanking everyone diminishes the praise you heap on really great answers. For another, you can't very well thank the author of a poor answer (and there are plenty of them), so the omission amounts to "I found your answer useless".

Comment: @CarySwoveland got it and will remember this next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @eirikir has shown you the error or your ways, I will address another issue.

Try this:

```
def tasty?(ripe)
  if ripe==true
    puts "Yes"
  else
    puts "Not Yet"
  end
end
```

Then

```
tasty?(true)  #=> "Yes"
tasty?(false) #=> "Not Yet"
tasty?(nil)   #=> "Not Yet"
tasty?(42)    #=> "Not Yet"
```

The last returns "Not Yet" because:

```
 42==true #=> false
```

Now try this:

```
def tasty?(ripe)
  if ripe
    puts "Yes"
  else
    puts "Not Yet"
  end
end
```

Then:

```
tasty?(true)  #=> "Yes"
tasty?(false) #=> "Not Yet"
tasty?(nil)   #=> "Not Yet"
tasty?(42)    #=> "Yes"
```

`tasty?(42)` now returns `"Yes"` because `ripe` evaluates `true`. That's because, in a logical expression (e.g., `if..`) an object evaluates `true` (is said to be "truthy") if it equals any value other than `false` or `nil`. It's said to be "falsy" if it equals `false` or `nil`.

@craig has shown how you can simplify the later expression.

Comment: Yes @caryswoveland this helped me a lot! Finally was able to work. I noticed my errors immediately after reading everyone's replies!

Answer (score 3):

The error you're receiving is due to a string in the `if` statement; you should remove the quotes, e.g.:

```
if ripe == 'yes'
```

However, since `ripe` is apparently always a boolean `true` or `false` and not a string `"yes"`, you shouldn't be comparing it to `"yes"`. You should be able to pass it directly to the `if` statement:

```
if ripe
  …
else
  …
end
```

Then you can simply return the desired strings for the different conditions:

```
if ripe
  "Yes"
else
  "Not yet"
end
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes @eirikir, this makes perfect sense! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the spec, I would write it this way:

```
def tasty?(ripe)
  ripe ? 'Yes' : 'Not Yet'
end
```

This can also be written more verbosely as:

```
def tasty?(ripe) 
  if ripe
    'Yes'
  else 
    'Not Yet' 
  end 
end
```

The parameter to your method, `ripe` is going to be - based on the spec you provided - true or false. So, in your method you need to check if `ripe` is true or false and then return the correct string (i.e., Yes or Not yet).

My first example uses the [ternary operator](https://www.codecademy.com/glossary/ruby/ternary-operator) which is a shorthand expression for an if/else statement (as shown in my second code block).

Basically, it is just asking if ripe is true and, if so, it returns 'Yes'. If not, it returns 'Not Yet'.

Comment: Thank you, too @craig.kaminsky! I have to do some follow-up on the ternary operator. Finally worked and I appreciate your help!